Can I force a program to require UAC just to run UN-elevated?
This is the opposite of most questions like "how do I run elevated without triggering UAC?" Instead, I would like to restrict a program to require UAC anytime it runs (aka only Administrators can run it), but when it runs it does not have elevated privileges.
This is a security goal. I have a program that has the potential to be exploited, and its current function does not require any elevated privileges, so I would like to prevent non-Administrators from running it, and prevent it from gaining elevated privileges when it does run.
Is this possible? (on Windows 11 Enterprise)

If UAC prompt is presented the permissions of the process WILL be elevated.  There is no way to present the UAC and prevent the permissions of the process from being elevated.

probably best to remove read/execute from the exes for all groups but admin. if you want to run it under a differant account consider runas.

Removing read/execute was what I settled on, yeah
